# wix: How to prevent user from restarting machine during the installation or upgrading of application

Tags: c#, installation, wix, windows-installer

There is the possibility that machine is shutdown/reboot/logoff when an update\installation is happening which might corrupt the install.

If we have the rollback option in place by scheduling RemoveExistingProducts afterInstallInitialize, will it resume the installation\update after machine restarts?

If there is a way in wix such that we can prevent user from restarting and logging off during the installation\upgrade?

How can we make the wix installer resumes its remaining work after the restart or even after abrupt shutdown (via hardware)?

**Update**

We have a desktop application deployed to our clients. There is a provision for our client to auto upgrade to the latest version. Our application will download the latest version of the msi and run the msiexex.exe command in the silent at background so that user would not have to do anything. All things will be done silent at the background. It was working perfectly. Now, some of our client complains that they had v2.1 earlier but it has gone now. We are thinking following possible cases:

1. During the upgrade, the latest version of the MSI is downloaded and it will be invoked using the command MSIEXEC.exe at the background by the application itself. The uninstallation of the installed (existing) version is completed but installation of new version gets failed leaving both versions uninstalled from the machine.

   As per reading different forums, it appears that the rollback in wix occurs  only if there is failure in the uninstallation of the existing version.
   So, my question is:
   If there is any error during the installation of the new version, will it roll back to the existing version?
2. Since user will never know that update of the application is going on as it will be done in silent mode, the user may restart or shutdown their machine in the meantime of upgrade. So, my initial question was: will the installation be corrupted if the machine is restarted or shut down in the middle of installation. Like you said, if all things are in transactional and are designed to recover from reboots at any time, then it is good for us. So, do you mean that we do not have to handle such case ourselves? It will be handled automatically by wix?

So, could it be the case#1 that cause the application to be uninstalled during the upgrade? Or Could there be any other possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer restarts after a reboot just fine, even if the reboot is during the installation phase. There is even a ForceReboot action to force this to happen if the install needs it, and there is an AFTERREBOOT property that is set to detect if there was a reboot during the installation.

If the RemoveExistingProducts (REP) is just after InstallInitialize then it is within the transaction, and a failure of the upgrade will result in rolling back the upgrade, and this includes rolling back the REP and installing the previously installed product. However this is a scenario that many installs don't test, and a failure to reinstall the product will result in neither of the products being installed. This is nothing to do with reboots, it's just that rolling back a REP is basically a silent install of the older product, requiring all essential properties to be restored and custom actions to behave properly. This seems to be your issue if your clients find nothing installed after a failed upgrade.

If REP is after InstallFinalize it is outside the transaction. That means the newer product is installed, the transaction finishes, then the old product is uninstalled, and if that fails you'll be left with both old and new products installed.

If you are using WiX and bundles to install or upgrade multiple MSIs then there is a Rollback boundary to control how much to roll back in a series of MSIs.

Again, it doesn't matter if there is a reboot - Windows Installer can deal with that fine, and it looks like your rollback failed to reinstall the original product. You should do the upgrade taking a complete verbose log (which IMO should be the default if you control the command line and can add the logging options). The log should show any failures during the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question. Please see my response in the update section.